# Issue when reading from `data.in` and writing on `data.out` in C

Tags: c, system-calls

I have been experimenting lately a lot with `fork()` and I am currently trying to learn how to handle parent and child processes. I am stuck on the code I'm working on because basically my program has to generate a child process, that has to open an input file, `data.in`, read the first ten and the last ten chars from it and write them on an output file `data.out`. Forking and opening both files goes smoothly. My issue is when I try to read from `data.in` and write on `data.out`, my program seems to skip the cycle or entering and skipping the write part and I can't figure out why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int in_fd;
    int out_fd;
    int pid;
    int read_bytes;
    int cursor_position = 0;
    char *buffer_in;
    char *buffer_out;


    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore: numero di parametri errato.\n");
        printf("Utilizzo: ./firstlast10 <file input> <file output>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (argc > 3)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Attenzione: numero di parametri errato. Gli input in eccedenza saranno ignorati.\n");
    }

    out_fd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if (out_fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del file. Errore no. %d.\n", errno);
        exit(errno); 
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        in_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if (in_fd < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del file. Errore no. %d.\n", errno);
            exit(errno); 
        }

        // Read 10 characters from the start.
        read(in_fd, buffer_in, 10);

        // Write the 10 characters.
        write(out_fd, buffer_in, 10);

        // Go to 10 characters before the end.
        lseek(in_fd, -10, SEEK_END);

        // Read last 10 characters.
        read(in_fd, buffer_in, 10);

        // Write the 10 characters.
        write(out_fd, buffer_in, 10);

        /*lseek(in_fd, -10, SEEK_END);

        while (read(in_fd, buffer_in, 64) > 0 && (lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) < 10))
        {
            write(out_fd, buffer_out, 64);
        }*/

        if (close(in_fd) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore nella chiusura del file. Errore no. %d.", errno);
            exit(errno);
        }

    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nella creazione del processo figlio. Errore no. %d.\n", errno);
        exit(errno);
    }


    if (close(out_fd) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nella chiusura del file. Errore no. %d.", errno);
        exit(errno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope you can help me shed some light on what's goin' on with my code.

Comment: Can you verify `cursor_position` is less than 10 to start?

Comment: @FiddlingBits, yes it does start at 0.

Comment: `read` must be failing then.  If you're getting a valid file descriptor, the read file might be empty???

Comment: @FiddlingBits it's not, I check every time. That is why I am getting mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simpler than what you have:

```
// Read 10 characters from the start.
read(in_fd, buffer_in, 10);

// Write the 10 characters.
write(out_fd, buffer_in, 10);

// Go to 10 characters before the end.
lseek(in_fd, -10, SEEK_END)

// Read last 10 characters.
read(in_fd, buffer_in, 10);

// Write the 10 characters.
write(out_fd, buffer_in, 10);
```

**Update**

The problem is that you have defined `buffer_in` as:

```
char *buffer_in;
```

You have not allocated any memory for it. You are seeing undefined behavior. Change it to:

```
char buffer_in[10];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately still no chars copied.

Comment: @haunted85 In your code you are using `buffer_out`. Are you still using that? I don't see `buffer_out` initialized anywhere in your posted code.

Comment: Yeah that was an error. Fixed and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `buffer_out` and `buffer_in` are not initialized. You're reading data into some random place in memory. No guarantee that memory is not changed somehow between your read and write operation.

Make sure you allocate appropriate buffer and use it. (Oh, and drop the `_in` and `_out` suffixes, they are not needed as you need only one buffer.)

Additionaly, once you declared `int read_bytes`, use it – assign the number of bytes you have read, and verify if it's equal to what you want (that is, 10). Similary for write.